# Jquery : delay fadeOut & clearQueue doesn't work?

Tags: jquery, queue, delay, settimeout

I don't understand why this code doesn't work:

```
function Messages(type,text) {
    console.log("In function Message");
    $("#message").clearQueue();
    console.log("clearQueue :"+$("#message").queue("fx").length+" effet in queue");

    if($("#message").length > 0 && $("#message").not(":visible").length == 1) {
         $("#message").slideDown("slow");
    }

    $("#message").queue(function(){
         $(this).delay(5000).fadeOut("slow");
         $(this).dequeue();
    });
    console.log("Adding  "+$("#message").queue("fx").length+" effet in queue");
 }
```

And this is the console log:

```
 In function Message
 1346clearQueue :0 effet in queue
 1356Adding  2 effet in queue
```

But it seems like clearQueue doesn't work because I have this:

Message appears,  he disappears 5 second after..

Message appears, after 4 seconds, I call "Message" again, and #Message disappears after one seconds.

So, if Message is called more than one time, the delay doesn't change and #Message disappears allways 5 seconds after the first call..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) is a [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) wrapper, so clearing the queue simply has no effect on it at all (at least not yet, hoping this changes in a future jQuery release).   When the delay is set, [`.dequeue()`](http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/) is [called on the element](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/queue.js#L84) when it finishes.

If you want to clear this you need to store the timeout yourself, something jQuery doesn't currently do internally.  Doing it yourself looks like this:

```
function Messages(type,text) {
    var msg = $("#message");
    //clear old timer
    clearTimeout(msg.data("timer"));
    //clear previous queue
    msg.clearQueue();

    if(msg.filter(":hidden").length == 1) msg.slideDown("slow");

    //set and store a new timer
    msg.data("timer", setTimeout(function() { msg.fadeOut("slow"); }, 5000));
}
```